# hide products from users who are not logged in (using tags)?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Pretty simple concept... I want to hide all products that have the tag "Wholesale" from everywhere in WooCommerce if the user is not logged in... I have gotten close, but no dice just yet.

**What I Have Currently**

```
$product_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $product->id, 'product_tag' );

if ( ! empty( $product_tags ) ) {
    foreach( $product_tags as $tag ) {
        if ( $tag->slug === 'wholesale' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

***See Gist: https://gist.github.com/DerekFoulk/d94646da9f22d5dddff6***

The results of my efforts can be seen on this page: http://gigacord.com/shop/

As you can see from the results, there are holes in the product grid because the row is supposed to have the class `.first` on product 1/3 (on each row) and `.last` on item 3/3. Where I am currently "removing" the product is apparently after the logic that counts the items per row and then assigns said classes.

This snippet does not do everything I would like. In a nutshell, I would like to remove the product from the products array as soon as possible (before my theme can start constructing its elements). I would also like to hide all product information when the product page is accessed directly (probably a different question though).

So, is there a WooCommerce hook that runs everywhere products are displayed, and if so, how can I hide the products that have the tag of "Wholesale" using that hook?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your loop...Also, using `:first-child` and `:last-child` CSS selectors may allow you to completely get rid of the `.first` and `.last` classes

Comment: @rnevius - Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/DerekFoulk/gigacord-wp

Comment: @rnevius - Agreed, this particular symptom could be remedied by using those selectors. This theme is not the most semantic, and there are definitely some less-than-perfect styles. I will see about updating those selectors as they will most likely solve that particular issue :)

Comment: Check [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61683/6477) I suspect it can be modified to fit your needs.

Comment: Ah, so those `.first` and `.last` selectors are use to clear the floats for each row. So, the proposed pseudo-selectors would not suffice, however `:nth-child(3n)` may do the trick :)

Comment: yes you'd better off using `pre_get_posts` than what you have now...

Comment: @helgatheviking - Thanks for the tip. I will look for solutions using this filter. I wish I knew a bit more about WordPress development at this point... For today, I am using the Groups plugin, but this requires me to set permissions on a product to product basis. I hope this filter is the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

it's better you use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Examples)

here...

```
function rei_exclude_by_product_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $taxquery = array(
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 6 ), // the ID of the product tag
                    'operator'=> 'NOT IN' // exclude
                )
            );

        $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rei_exclude_by_product_tag' );
```

Comment: Nicely done. I wasn't sure if you could tell `is_user_logged_in()` on `pre_get_posts`, but great!

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this tomorrow and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Reigel!! Was looking for this.

Side Note on "Reigel": (for those looking into the Category)

> You can swap "product_tag" with "product_cat" too.

Worked for me when targeting my *public* category.

Comment: I did, but thank you for replying...