# WooCommerce - How to hide products newer than 2 years old if user not logged in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a website for a client who is a wholesale dealer. He only wants his approved, logged in customers to be able to see all of his products, while hiding anything newer than 2 years old from users who aren't logged in as they could be his competitors.

My searches on ways to do this lead me to this link:  [hide products from users who are not logged in (using tags)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684881/hide-products-from-users-who-are-not-logged-in-using-tags)

This code looks like it's heading the right direction of what I need:

```
function rei_exclude_by_product_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $taxquery = array(
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( 6 ), // the ID of the product tag
                    'operator'=> 'NOT IN' // exclude
                )
            );

        $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'rei_exclude_by_product_tag' );
```

But I don't need to hide products according to taxonomy, it needs to be if the product is newer than 2 years old.

He previously just wanted the "Add to Cart" buttons hidden, so for that I wrote this function which worked nicely:

```
function check_product_age(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $product;
        $json_product = json_decode($product);
        $date_created = date_create($json_product->date_created->date);
        $date_stripped = date_format($date_created, 'Y-m-d');
        $today = date('Y-m-d');

        $days = (strtotime($today) - strtotime($date_stripped)) / (60 * 60 * 24);

        if($days <= 730){
            echo('<style>.cart{display:none!important;}</style>');
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'check_product_age' );
```

Not sure if that helps at all or if any of the above code can be changed to suit my clients needs, but hopefully someone here can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Date_Parameters) you can see that there is a `date_query` parameter that has `after` to narrow the search, so you can use that instead.

You would replace the query type with `$query->set('date_query', $taxquery)` and then set the `$taxquery` variable to:

```
$taxquery = array(
                array(
                    'after' => strtotime( "-730 days" ) // yes, it really is that simple!
                )
            );
```

Finally, for clarity, rename the `$taxquery` variable to `$datequery` - I've kept it the same for the above just so you can easily see what to change.

Note: this is in theory as I'm not at my desk right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Peter HvD.  Your answer didn't quite get me there, but it was very very close indeed and it did certainly point me in the right direction.  It became clearer once I read through the Codex that you directed me to.

For anyone else out there wanting to achieve something like this, here is the final function that I ended up with which now works 100%:

```
// HIDE ALL PRODUCTS NEWER THAN 2 YEARS OLD IF NOT LOGGED IN //
function db_exclude_new_products( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_woocommerce() && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $datequery = array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                'before' => '2 years ago'
            )
        );

        $query->set('date_query', $datequery);
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'db_exclude_new_products' );
```

Comment: Ah... misread your question - I though you wanted to only show products newer than 2 years (and I just grabbed the 730 days from your 2nd bit of code). Glad to have helped though :-)

Comment: No worries.  Got there in the end and my client is very happy now.  :-)
Thanks.